# Consumer not receiving messages, kafka console, new consumer api, Kafka 0.9

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am doing the [Kafka Quickstart](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart) for Kafka 0.9.0.0.

I have zookeeper listening at `localhost:2181` because I ran

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

I have a single broker listening at `localhost:9092` because I ran

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

I have a producer posting to topic "test" because I ran

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
yello
is this thing on?
let's try another
gimme more
```

When I run the old API consumer, it *works* by running

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

However, when I run the new API consumer, I don't get anything when I run

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer --topic test --from-beginning \
    --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Is it possible to subscribe to a topic from the console consumer using the new api? How can I fix it?

Comment: What scala version are you using? Did you compile compile kafka? I had a couple of minor issue with kafka_2.10-0.9.0.0.tgz but with kafka_2.101-0.9.0.0.tgz it works like a charm, your example included.

Comment: Ok thanks, this was with 2.10. If I try again it will be with 2.11.

Comment: did you create 'test' topic?

Answer (score 68):

I my MAC box I was facing the same issue of console-consumer not consuming any messages when used the command

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9095 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic
```

But when I tried with

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9095 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic --partition 0
```

It happily lists the messages sent. Is this a bug in Kafka 1.10.11?

Comment: this worked for me too..but why do we have to mention partition number

Comment: it worked after passing argument `--partition 0` at the end.

Comment: I found the same problem on 2.x too. This answer solved it.

Comment: This is just a patch solution,  I recommend  verify all the warn and error logs on zookeeper and kafka brokers. Once the cluster  is healthy is possible try to read using boostrap servers.

Comment: Why is this solution working? Is this a bug in Kafka?

Comment: You should check if topic `__consumer_offsets` is created in kafka, when this topic is not present you should specify partition manually.
For me the reason this topic was not created, was this configutation option: `offsets.topic.replication.factor`, if the number of brokers is less than this parameter, offset_topic will not be created

Comment: but how can we read from all partitions at once, if possible?

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into this issue and the solution was to delete `/brokers` in zookeeper and restart the kafka nodes.

`bin/zookeeper-shell <zk-host>:2181`

and then

`rmr /brokers`

Not sure why this solves it.

When I enabled debug logging, I saw this error message over and over again in the consumer:

`2017-07-07 01:20:12 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:548 - Sending GroupCoordinator request for group test to broker xx.xx.xx.xx:9092 (id: 1007 rack: null)
2017-07-07 01:20:12 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:559 - Received GroupCoordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1499390412231, latencyMs=84, disconnected=false, requestHeader={api_key=10,api_version=0,correlation_id=13,client_id=consumer-1}, responseBody={error_code=15,coordinator={node_id=-1,host=,port=-1}}) for group test
2017-07-07 01:20:12 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:581 - Group coordinator lookup for group test failed: The group coordinator is not available.
2017-07-07 01:20:12 DEBUG AbstractCoordinator:215 - Coordinator discovery failed for group test, refreshing metadata`

Comment: I am using CDH 5.13 and CDK 4.0 (apache 2.1). Getting the same problem. However, consumer is still not getting messages after deleting brokers and topics as suggested by you.

Comment: This solutions worked for me, but it was not easy as just remove all the references on zookeeper, I've deleted the log files on kafka brokers and ensure the cluster is healthy, I made several corrections on the cluster and I didn't make a list of all the fixes applied,  what I recommend is access to the zookeeper and kafka server logs and review an try to remove all the errors and warning messages.

Answer (score 9):

For me the solution described in this thread worked - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51540528/7568227

Check if

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor
```

(or probably other config parameters related to replication)
is not higher than the number of brokers. That was the problem in my case.

There was no need to use --partition 0 anymore after this fix.

Otherwise I recommend to follow the debugging procedure described in the mentioned thread.

Comment: Hey miko, thanks for answering a question on StackOVerflow :-)
Since the original thread's essential part is the debugging procedure you mention, please transfer it into your question.

Comment: @miko - You sir, are a real hero.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, this doesn't work

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic
```

and this works

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic --partition 0
```

because the topic `__consumer_offsets` was located on the unaccessible broker. Basically, I'd forgotten to replicate it. Relocating `__consumer_offsets` solved my issue.

Comment: How to Relocating __consumer_offsets topic?

Comment: My problem is  __consumer_offsets topic too, when I move brokers to different nodes, this topic still stores data in old nodes. I just stop all the Kafka services, using Zookeeper CLI to delete this topic manually, then restart all the Kafka services and now the error is gone

Answer (score 5):

Was getting the same issue on my Mac.
I checked the logs and found the following error.

```
Number of alive brokers '1' does not meet the required replication factor '3' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). 
This error can be ignored if the cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet.
```

This can be fixed by changing the replication factor to 1. Add the following line in server.properties and restart Kafka/Zookeeper.

```
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
```

Comment: Any clue on how to set this up while running it inside docker, Following this tutorial : https://kafka-tutorials.confluent.io/kafka-console-consumer-producer-basics/kafka.html and facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem, now I have figured out.

When you use --zookeeper, it is supposed to be provided with zookeeper address as parameter.

When you use --bootstrap-server, it is supposed to be provided with broker address as parameter.

Comment: The question says they are already providing a broker address as a parameter; Port 9092 is the default Kafka port.

Comment: well, no always, if you download the HDP sandbox for docker it defaults it to 6667

Answer (score 2):

Your localhost is the foo here.
if you replace the localhost word for the actual hostname, it should work.

like this:

producer

```
./bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list \
sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:9092 --topic test
```

consumer:

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic test --from-beginning \    
--bootstrap-server bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --new-consumer \
--topic test --from-beginning \
--bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Comment: The command for consumer is incorrect. Can you please correct it?

Answer (score 2):

This problem also impacts ingesting data from the kafka using flume and sink the data to HDFS.

To fix the above issue:

1. Stop Kafka brokers
2. Connect to zookeeper cluster and remove /brokers z node
3. Restart kafka brokers

There is no issue with respect to kafka client version and scala version that we are using the cluster. Zookeeper might have wrong information about broker hosts.

To verify the action:

Create topic in kafka.

```
$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server slavenode01.cdh.com:9092 --topic rkkrishnaa3210 --from-beginning
```

Open a producer channel and feed some messages to it.

```
$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list slavenode03.cdh.com:9092 --topic rkkrishnaa3210
```

Open a consumer channel to consume the message from a specific topic.

```
$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server slavenode01.cdh.com:9092 --topic rkkrishnaa3210 --from-beginning
```

To test this from flume:

Flume agent config:

```
rk.sources  = source1
rk.channels = channel1
rk.sinks = sink1

rk.sources.source1.type = org.apache.flume.source.kafka.KafkaSource
rk.sources.source1.zookeeperConnect = ip-20-0-21-161.ec2.internal:2181
rk.sources.source1.topic = rkkrishnaa321
rk.sources.source1.groupId = flume1
rk.sources.source1.channels = channel1
rk.sources.source1.interceptors = i1
rk.sources.source1.interceptors.i1.type = timestamp
rk.sources.source1.kafka.consumer.timeout.ms = 100
rk.channels.channel1.type = memory
rk.channels.channel1.capacity = 10000
rk.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity = 1000
rk.sinks.sink1.type = hdfs
rk.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path = /user/ce_rk/kafka/%{topic}/%y-%m-%d
rk.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollInterval = 5
rk.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
rk.sinks.sink1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
rk.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
rk.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
```

Run flume agent:

```
flume-ng agent --conf . -f flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n rk
```

Observe logs from the consumer that the message from the topic is written in HDFS.

```
18/02/16 05:21:14 INFO internals.AbstractCoordinator: Successfully joined group flume1 with generation 1
18/02/16 05:21:14 INFO internals.ConsumerCoordinator: Setting newly assigned partitions [rkkrishnaa3210-0] for group flume1
18/02/16 05:21:14 INFO kafka.SourceRebalanceListener: topic rkkrishnaa3210 - partition 0 assigned.
18/02/16 05:21:14 INFO kafka.KafkaSource: Kafka source source1 started.
18/02/16 05:21:14 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Monitored counter group for type: SOURCE, name: source1: Successfully registered new MBean.
18/02/16 05:21:14 INFO instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SOURCE, name: source1 started
18/02/16 05:21:41 INFO hdfs.HDFSDataStream: Serializer = TEXT, UseRawLocalFileSystem = false
18/02/16 05:21:42 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Creating /user/ce_rk/kafka/rkkrishnaa3210/18-02-16/FlumeData.1518758501920.tmp
18/02/16 05:21:48 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Closing /user/ce_rk/kafka/rkkrishnaa3210/18-02-16/FlumeData.1518758501920.tmp
18/02/16 05:21:48 INFO hdfs.BucketWriter: Renaming /user/ce_rk/kafka/rkkrishnaa3210/18-02-16/FlumeData.1518758501920.tmp to /user/ce_rk/kafka/rkkrishnaa3210/18-02-16/FlumeData.1518758501920
18/02/16 05:21:48 INFO hdfs.HDFSEventSink: Writer callback called.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Note:  Remove `--new-consumer` from your command

For reference see here: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart

Comment: Then it will not use the new consumer, and the question is how to get messages using the new consumer.

Comment: 0.9.0.0 in this version of Kafka, their new console consumer was not working, they gave java consumer but not console consumer. And now they have removed "--new-consumer" from later versions completely.

Comment: This answer was edited after I corrected it, so please disregard my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try like this:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --from-beginning --topic my-replicated-topic
```

Comment: This command is for running Old Consumer API. Your answer is already mentioned in Problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it didn't worked using either approaches then I also increased the log level to **DEBUG** at `config/log4j.properties`, started the console consumer

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --from-beginning --topic MY_TOPIC
```

Then got the log below

```
[2018-03-11 12:11:25,711] DEBUG [MetadataCache brokerId=10] Error while fetching metadata for MY_TOPIC-3: leader not available (kafka.server.MetadataCache)
```

The point here is that I have two kafka nodes but one is down, by some reason by default kafka-console consumer will not consume if there is some  partition not available because the node is down (the partition 3 in that case). It doesn't happen in my application.

**Possible solutions are**

- Startup the down brokers
- Delete the topic and create it again that way all partitions will be placed at the online broker node

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command from bin:

```sh
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic test --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

"test" is the topic name

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem that consumer finished executing 
in **kafka_2.12-2.3.0.tgz**.

Tried debugging but no logs were printed.

Try running fine with **kafka_2.12-2.2.2**
.Works fine.

And try running the zookeeper and kafka from the [quickstart guide](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)!

Answer (score -3):

In kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0 the zookeeper server is deprecated and and it is using bootstrap-server, and it will take broker ip address and port. If you give correct broker parameters you will be able to consume messages.

e.g. $ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server :9093 --topic test --from-beginning

I'm using port 9093, for you it may vary.

regards.

Answer (score -4):

replication factor must be at least 3

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic test
```