# Kafka consumer not able to consume messages using bootstrap server name

Tags: apache-kafka, producer-consumer

I am facing an issue while consuming message using the bootstrap-server i.e. Kafka server. Any idea why is it not able to consume messages without zookeeper?

- Kafka Version: kafka_2.11-1.0.0
- Zookeeper Version: kafka_2.11-1.0.0
- Zookeeper Host and port: zkp02.mp.com:2181
- Kafka Host and port: kfk03.mp.com:9092

Producing some message:

```
[kfk03.mp.com ~]$ /bnsf/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list kfk03.mp.com:9092 --topic test
>hi
>hi
```

Consumer not able to consume messages if I give `–-bootstrap-server`:

```
[kfk03.mp.com ~]$
/bnsf/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kfk03.mp.com:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Consumer able to consume messages when `--zookeeper` server is given instead of `--bootstrap-server` -:

```
[kfk03.mp.com ~]$ /bnsf/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper zkp02.mp.com:2181 --topic test --from-beginning

Using the ConsoleConsumer with old consumer is deprecated and will be removed in a future major release. Consider using the new consumer by passing [bootstrap-server] instead of [zookeeper].

{"properties": {"messageType": "test", "sentDateTime": "2018-02-25T21:46:00.000+0000"}, "name": "Uttam Anand", "age": 29}
{"properties": {"messageType": "test", "sentDateTime": "2018-02-25T21:46:00.000+0000"}, "name": "Uttam Anand", "age": 29}
{"properties": {"messageType": "test", "sentDateTime": "2018-02-25T21:46:00.000+0000"}, "name": "Uttam Anand", "age": 29}
hi
{"properties": {"messageType": "test", "sentDateTime": "2018-02-25T21:46:00.000+0000"}, "name": "Uttam Anand", "age": 29}
{"properties": {"messageType": "test", "sentDateTime": "2018-02-25T21:46:00.000+0000"}, "name": "Uttam Anand", "age": 29}
{"properties": {"messageType": "test", "sentDateTime": "2018-02-25T21:46:00.000+0000"}, "name": "Uttam Anand", "age": 29}
{"properties": {"messageType": "test", "sentDateTime": "2018-02-25T21:46:00.000+0000"}, "name": "Uttam Anand", "age": 29}
{"properties": {"messageType": "test", "sentDateTime": "2018-02-25T21:46:00.000+0000"}, "name": "Uttam Anand", "age": 29}
hi
hi
uttam
hi
hi
hi
hello
hi
^CProcessed a total of 17 messages
```

Comment: server.properties

broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
port=9092
host.name=kfk03.mp.com
advertised.host.name=kfk03.mp.com
advertised.port=9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/bnsf/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=1440
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
zookeeper.connect=zkp02.mp.com:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=60000

Comment: Newer versions of Kafka took some processes away from zookeeper and into the Kafka brokers. This enabled them to protect zookeeper from unexpected outages. Although main operational functionalities retained in zookeeper.
That's why your consumers are able to consume messages when --zookeeper is given not --bootstrap-server

Answer (score 16):

While consuming messages from kafka using bootstrap-server parameter, the connection happens via the kafka server instead of zookeeper. Kafka broker stores offset details in __consumer_offsets topic.

Check if __consumer_offsets is present in your topics list. If it's not there, check kafka logs to find the reason.

We faced a similar issue. In our case the __consumer_offsets was not created because of the following error:

```
ERROR [KafkaApi-1001] Number of alive brokers '1' does not meet the required replication factor '3' for the offsets topic (configured via 'offsets.topic.replication.factor').
```

Comment: Tnx for this hint. this costed me 3 h of debugging. cheers again

Comment: Same for me - waster 1 hr - finally found this!