# Kubernetes kafka - lagom - Consumer interrupted with WakeupException after timeout. Message: null

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, lagom

Using Lagom 1.4.11, kafka 0.11
The communication to kafka seems to be working, because the producers had produced something.
Only consumer has errors.

```
[WARN] [03/13/2019 19:36:45.937] [gui-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-8] [akka://gui/system/kafka-consumer-1] Consumer interrupted with WakeupException after timeout. Message: null. Current value of akka.kafka.consumer.wakeup-timeout is 3000 milliseconds
[WARN] [03/13/2019 19:36:50.080] [gui-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-10] [akka://gui/system/kafka-consumer-1] Consumer interrupted with WakeupException after timeout. Message: null. Current value of akka.kafka.consumer.wakeup-timeout is 3000 milliseconds
```

it seemes that my µService has no connection to the kafka. 
I hava a kafka-0 pod, kafka-zookeeper-0.

I installed it with

```
helm install --name kafka --namespace avalon bitnami/kafka -f values.yaml
```

Is their someone who can help.
Thank you.

added.

I found out that the producer created the topics:

```
I have no name!@kafka-0:/$ kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 10.***.21.50:2181 --list
item-issued-topic
topic-item-created
```

```
I have no name!@kafka-0:/$ kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-0:9092 --topic topic-item-created --from-beginning
^CProcessed a total of 0 messages
```

It seemes that kafka does not store the messages.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem, which was solved by looking at this document

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-com:9094 --topic test --from-beginning --partition 0
```

[Consumer not receiving messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844209/consumer-not-receiving-messages-kafka-console-new-consumer-api-kafka-0-9)